# Inlining Text between images in Apache FOP2

Tags: java, apache-fop

I'm trying to inline the text `test` between images, but as soon as I add text, I get spacing at the top and bottom of the text.

[image]

As I've [discovered earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891914/apache-fop2-is-adding-unwanted-spacing-between-images), in order to get rid of those top and bottom spacing that's breaking the image layout, I need to set the font-size to 0:

[image]

But font-size zero is pretty useless if you want to display text.

```
            <fo:block font-size="0" >
                <fo:external-graphic src=" http://www.mycee.com/image/20135-Test-Mockup-V1.0-01_13.jpg"/>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block background-color="pink" font-size="0pt" >
                <fo:external-graphic src="http://www.mycee.com/image/20135-Test-Mockup-V1.0-01_14.jpg"/>
                test
                <fo:external-graphic src="http://www.mycee.com/image/20135-Test-Mockup-V1.0-01_16.jpg"/>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block background-color="magenta" font-size="0" >
                <fo:external-graphic src=" http://www.mycee.com/image/20135-Test-Mockup-V1.0-01_17.jpg"/>
            </fo:block>
```

Putting the text inside `fo-inline`, I can at least get rid of the top padding, but there's still padding at the bottom breaking my layout.

```
    <fo:inline font-size="10pt">
    test
    </fo:inline>
```

[image]

What is the correct way to insert text between images without the text causing padding to appear at the top or bottom?

**Update**

Finally got it working

```
<fo:block background-color="pink" line-height="2.4mm" line-stacking-strategy="none" font-size="11pt">
                <fo:table>
                    <fo:table-column/>
                    <fo:table-column/>
                    <fo:table-column/>
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell text-align="left">
                                <fo:block>
                                    <fo:external-graphic
                                            src="http://www.mycee.com/images/20135-Test-Mockup-V1.0-01_14.jpg"/>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell text-align="right">
                                <fo:block>
                                    12345678.90
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell text-align="right">
                                <fo:block>
                                    <fo:external-graphic
                                            src="http://www.mycee.com/images/20135-Test-Mockup-V1.0-01_16.jpg"/>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
            </fo:block>
```

[image]

If you zoom enough, you'll eventually see a line, but for printing purposes, this is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "padding" you see *could* be due to the way line height is computed.

Line height is controlled by two different FO properties:

- [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#line-height) sets the starting value, the one deriving from the block's text content; its default value is `normal`, and FOP calculates it as 1.2 * `font-size`
- [`line-stacking-strategy`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#line-stacking-strategy) controls how the starting value is modified if the `fo:block` contains inline elements (`fo:inline`s, images, ...) besides simple text; it defaults to `max-height`, meaning (roughly speaking) that the line height is increased to fit images and inlines having larger font size

Now, let us look at your specific situation:

- `font-size` defaults to 12pt, which means that the initial value for line height is 1.2 * 12pt = 14.4pt; if the height of your images is less than that, they will appear having some space at the top and at the bottom
- setting `font-size="0pt"` kinda works, because the initial line height would be 0pt, which would be subsequently increased to the height of the images

**Suggested change:**

- try using `line-height="x" line-stacking-strategy="font-height"` (where `x` is the height of your images) in the `fo:block` elements containing text and images; the combined effect of these properties is to set the line height to the exact given value

*(disclosure: I'm a FOP developer, though not very active nowadays)*

Comment: I've tried line-height, but not with line-stacking-strategy.
Will give that try first thing tomorrow morning, thanks @Ifurini :-)

Comment: Finally got it working, had to use a block with a table inside and also using line-height and setting line-stacking-strategy to none and tinker with the line-height and font sizes until the lines disappeared.